# How can I get the results of the upcoming month's birthdays in Laravel?

Tags: sql, laravel

I have this code but I can't query only birthday of today. What should I do if I need this query type?

I need a birthday regardless of the year(Only day and month).

```
    public function birth(Request $request)
{

$today = Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d');


  $birthday = DB::table('customers')
                     ->select('id_user','first_name','last_name','birth_date','open_user_date')
                     ->where('birth_date',$today)
                     ->get();



      return view('reports/birth',compact('birthday','date','today','hbddate'));
  }
```

Comment: Your title talks about upcoming birthdays in 1 month, your question asks something about getting the amount of years between date of birth and today (which would be someone's age). Could you please make it more clear what you try to achieve? Or have a look at [whereBetween](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#where-clauses)

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code to get the customers having birthday today.

```
$today = Carbon::now()->format('m-d');

$birthday = DB::table('customers')
                         ->select('id_user','first_name','last_name','birth_date','open_user_date')
                         ->where(DB::raw(DATE_FORMAT(birthDate,'%m-%d'), $today))
                         ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

I checked [all possible where clauses](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/queries#where-clauses). Maybe whereDay and whereMonth are those that you need.

```
$day = now()->day;
$month = now()->month;

$customers = DB::table('customers')
    ->whereDay($day)
    ->whereMonth($month)
    ->get();
```